# Command: flutter create . cannot execute

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a web folder of my repository in order to push it to github and host it with githubPages.
When I run this command:

```
flutter create .
```

It returns an error:

```
Cannot execute 

Please run command with  --verbose if you want more information
```

- SDK path is correct in Flutter and Dart.
- Cannot excuted flutter doctor for the same reason
- Flutter version 3.3.10

Comment: And what happens when you run `flutter create . --verbose`?

Comment: same log as mentioned before